# Why is the second bash script not printing its iteration?

Tags: bash

I have two bash scripts:

a.sh:

```
echo "running"
doit=true     

if [ $doit = true ];then
   ./b.sh &
fi

some-long-operation-binary
echo "done"
```

b.sh:

```
for i in {0..50}; do
  echo "counting";
  sleep 1;
done
```

I get this output:

```
  > ./a.sh
running
counting
```

Why do I only see the first "counting" from `b.sh` and then nothing anymore? (Currently `some-long-operation-binary` just `sleep 5` for this example). I first thought that due to setting `b.sh` in the background, its STDOUT is lost, but why do I see the first output? More importantly: is b.sh still running and doing its thing (its iteration)?

For context:
`b.sh` is going to poll a service provided by `some-long-operation-binary`, which is only available after some time the latter has run, and when ready, would write its content to a file.

Apologies if this is just rubbish, it's a bit late...

Comment: `sleep 21600`. At least.

Comment: can't wait too long either, or it might terminate and I don't get the desired content.

Comment: `Why do I only see the first "counting" from b.sh and then nothing anymore?` Do you have `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`? Please print `echo "counting $i"`.

Comment: Expanding KamilCuk's question: some shells (like bash, zsh, and ksh) will expand `{0..50}` to a list of integers from 0 to 50, but some others (like dash) won't; they'll just run the loop once, with `i` set to the string "{0..50}". So you need to make sure b.sh runs in the right shell. (Making sure a.sh runs in the right shell wouldn't hurt either.)

Comment: if the shell you're using doesn't support brace expansion (`{0..50}`) there are other looping constructs to try, eg, `for ((i=1;i<=50;i++)) ...` or manually incrementing a counter `while [ $counter -le 50 ] ...`

Comment: @KamilCuk adding the shebang did it. I totally forwent that I was developing locally on a box where I have `zsh`, but the scripts have to run on a box with `bash`...

If you care, that should be the answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `#!/bin/bash` or the like to `b.sh` that uses a Bash-like expansion, to make sure Bash is actually running the script. Otherwise there may be (indeed) only one loop iteration happening.

When you start a background process, it is usually a good practice to kill it and wait for it, no matter which way the script exits.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e -o pipefail

declare -i show_counter=1

counter() {
  local -i i
  for ((i = 0;; ++i)); do
    echo "counting $((i))"
    sleep 1
  done
}

echo starting

if ((show_counter)); then
  counter &
  declare -i counter_pid="${!}"
  trap 'kill "${counter_pid}"
        wait -n "${counter_pid}" || :
        echo terminating' EXIT
fi

sleep 10  # long-running process
```