# While loop in bash behaves strange if called in the background

Tags: bash

I asked this question: [Why is the second bash script not printing its iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68825374/why-is-the-second-bash-script-not-printing-its-iteration)

which is the basis for this one...in fact, I thought the above one would solve my problem but it doesn't.

I run a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#do some stuff
if ${do_poll}; then
  echo "Polling..."
  runs_own=true
  source "${scripts_path}/scripts/poll.sh" &
fi

"${run_path}/binary" --json="${json}"
```

The idea is that `poll.sh` starts in the background. Then `binary` starts, which has to do some setup, and at some point it starts a webserver which will offer some diagnostics data. `poll.sh` is supposed to poll that webserver until it can reach the webserver.

`poll.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

http_code=0
URL="localhost:9999"    

while [ $http_code -ne 200 ]
do
  echo "Not ready yet..."
  response=$(curl -s -w '\n%{http_code}' $URL)
  http_code=$(tail -n1 <<< "$response")
  content=$(sed '$ d' <<< "$response") 
  sleep 1
done
#do something with $content
```

The issue I am having is that if I run the main script, then `poll.sh` separately from the shell it works just fine, at some point I get the `$content` and the scripts does its job, but if I call it from the main script and put it in the background as above, then I only can see

"Not ready yet..."

one time and then nothing else from the poll script ever. It looks like it's hanging after the curl call (or exits there, not sure) - if I add some bogus `echo` after the `curl`, it never appears.

What could be the issue here?

**EDIT**
If I change the script to do the following (no `source`):

```
  ..
  export runs_own=true
  "${scripts_path}/scripts/poll.sh" &
fi
```

it works....

Therefore calling `source` is changing the behavior to one I am not expecting (not saying it's wrong, most probably I am using it wrong).

Comment: A background command (```poll.sh &```) is receiving a signal when its parent is terminating.
I wonder if this is your situation: does the main script ends after ```binary``` ends?

To avoid this you could use ```nohup``` :  ```nohup .../poll.sh &```

Comment: Great point but `"${run_path}/binary" --json="${json}"` is actually long-running and not exiting prematurely. It is still running when I stop getting output from the `poll` script.

Comment: I don't think it makes any sense to use `source` in the background. You use `source` if the script should modify the current shell environment, but a backgrounded command runs in a subshell so it can't affect the current environment.

Comment: One of the first steps when debugging a shell script is to put `set -x` at the beginning, so you can see the commands it's executing.

Comment: To be clear, the subshell you fork off with `source something &` should still be able to _see_ variables that were set before you started it; it just can't make changes to its parent's environment.

Comment: Instead of `sleep 1` in the loop, you should use one of the timeout options for `curl`.